# found input variables with inconsistent number of samples error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Im trying to train a model, however when I fit the model, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 3608]
```

Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/amanpuranik/Desktop/fake-news-detection/data.csv")
data = data[['Headline', "Label"]]
print(data)

x = data[["Headline"]]
y = data[["Label"]]
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
print(x_train.shape)



tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_df=1)

model = MultinomialNB()
#model.fit(x_train,y_train) #this part gives me a string to float error

pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tfidf_vectorizer), ('classifier', model)])

pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I am not sure how I could get past this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have one feature and 3608 records, but the code thinks there is one sample with 3608 features.

change the code where x and y are defined as follows.

```
x = data[["Headline"]].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = data["Label"].values
```